# When is an enum constructor called?

Tags: java

I'm implementing a deck of cards as a singleton, using an enum so that I can have universal access to the deck from anywhere in the program.  As part of the enum's constructor, it shuffles an arraylist with every card and pushes them all onto a stack (it just seems symbolically appropriate).

When is that constructor called?  Is it constructed at runtime?  Compile time?  The first time I make a call to the enum?  Can I expect that every time I run the program that the deck of cards will be properly randomized?

Thanks!

Comment: I recommend that you do not use singleton for the scenario you described.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use a singleton for this.

But to answer the question, the constructor is called when the enum class (Deck) is loaded by the classloader and initialized. So the deck will be shuffled before any line of code can call any method of the Deck class.

Comment: Why shouldn't I use a singleton for this?  It seems like a logical place to use a singleton.  It's something that most classes need access to and rather than pass references to an instance of the deck around to every class's constructor (and make sure that every class has a pointer to it), I'll just have every class reference the singleton whenever they need it.

Also, I should be clear: I'm not creating a classic deck of cards.  I am porting a board game to Java, so every card is unique (each card is part of another enumerated type).

Comment: A deck of cards doesn't constitute a unique resource. I could understand making a singleton for a datasource. But a deck of cards is typically something you have several instances of. Singletons should be avoided in general because they promote bad design (spaghetti code), and code that is hard to unit test (by mocking a deck). The fact that so many classes in your app need access to the deck is a sign that the design is perfectible.

Comment: It's funny, I'm pretty new to programming and I'm doing this project as a learning project.  When I first came across the idea of a singleton, it didn't mention that they were something to be avoided and so I just though it was a neat programming tool and started implementing them all over the place.  After seeing everyone's answers to this question, I was pretty surprised to learn that they were such a bad thing.  Very interesting.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are designing it the wrong way. An `enum` represent a set of finite values which is not supposed to have global functionality. They're just constants, which can have functionality for each of them but anything more is not worth doing it.

Bringing a shuffle functionality to a deck directly in an enum constructor (**which is called for every constant in any case**) doesn't seem the right way to do it.

A better solution would be to have 4 different classes, something like:

```
enum Suit {
  HEARTS,
  CLUBS,
  ..
}

enum Value {
  ACE,
  TWO,
  ..
}

class Card {
  Suit suit;
  Value value;
}

class Deck {
  List<Card> cards;

  public void shuffle() { .. }
}
```

Comment: In Java, using an `Enum` is the preferred way to create a singleton. That being said, I agree with the rest of your answer re: don't use a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

For each  enum type, the constructor is invoked when the Enum class is first initialized in order.